# Magento secure url to delete and edit product in the cart

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl, mini-cart, secure

in `code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php`

i changed getConfigureUrl and getDeleteUrl by adding _secure

```
public function getConfigureUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'checkout/cart/configure',
            array('id' => $this->getItem()->getId(), '_secure' => Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure())
        );
    }



public function getDeleteUrl()
    {   
        if ($this->hasDeleteUrl()) {
            return $this->getData('delete_url');
        }

        return $this->getUrl(
            'checkout/cart/delete',
            array(
                'id'=>$this->getItem()->getId(),
                Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl(),
                '_secure' => Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
            )
        );
    }
```

Still in secure pages like my account the configure url and delete url starts with http (unsecure) in the mini cart. How can i make the configure url and delete url secure in secure pages?

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
$this->getUrl('yourpage', array('_forced_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()));
```